# Words to say the "the purposed item"

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-meaning

Sometimes we address a specific "thing", "item"... Then we want to refer that item with something like "the desired item", "the item of interest" "the item to be selected", "the purposed item".

for example

> Otherwise, we can employ another anchor which has a common ancestor with the first anchor and encloses the ( our purposed?) section.

"Purposed" seems suitable for my meaning, but I didn't find much of it in google, what are the common words to address something in the way I described?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for *the target section*? Or *targeted* could also be used.

Comment: @Sander I look for a common word which means "purposed", target seems promising

Comment: Yea I've often heard 'target' used in this meaning. At my university for example, when we translate, the result of our translation is the *target text* written in the *target language*.

Comment: Maybe you want _item in question, item considered above, item under consideration, said item_

Comment: item : at issue, being discussed, under discussion, under consideration, on the agenda, for debate, to be discussed, to be decided

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use *purposed* this way. *Purposed* is the passive participle of the (now very rare) verb *purpose*, meaning "have as one's purpose": it designates your goal or object, not something on which you intend to operate in order to achieve your purpose.

We have in fact no attributive adjective or participle with the generic sense you intend. In any case, your best course is to employ whatever verb most precisely designates the operation you are carrying out; it is almost always better to be as precise as possible than to employ vague generics like *involved* or *targeted*. If what you're doing with that section is "parapositing" it (don't look that up, I just invented it), say so:

> ... encloses the **paraposited** section.
>   ... encloses the section **being paraposited**.
>   ... encloses the section **under paraposition**.

Your second-best course is to follow AmD's suggestion and employ a following participle or preposition phrase.

> ... encloses the section **involved**.
>   ... encloses the section **being operated upon**.
>   ... encloses the section **in play**.
>   ... encloses the section **under consideration**.

Comment: I wonder if **purposed** is also erroneously used **[here](https://www.bellingcat.com/news/uk-and-europe/2015/10/08/mh17-the-open-source-evidence/)**: "The Russian Ministry of Defense also presented radar data showing MH17 and claimed “Russian system of air control detected the Ukrainian Air Force aircraft, **purposed** Su-25, moving upwards toward to the Malaysian Boeing-777. The distance between aircrafts was 3-5 kilometers.” Chief of Staff of the Air Force Lieutenant-General Igor Makushev was then invited to comment on the radar data."

Comment: @CopperKettle That's certainly an error, probably of translation - your knowledge of Russian may suggest what was intended. There are others: *towards to*, *aircrafts*.